# Parse date in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Hi I am tring to parse this date string: "Tue Aug 25 14:06:30 2015" using Java. Here is my code and I keep getting a unparsable date error in the very first line:

```
d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy").parse("Tue Aug 25 14:06:30 2015");
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d1);
String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Check what `MM` means in your format text, vs what you want it to mean. Also note that you should be specifying the locale and probably the time zone.

Comment: Check out the examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You probably need `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

To parse abbreviated text for the month, you need 3 `M` characters, not 2, which expects a number such as `08`.  According to the [Javadocs for `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

Try:

```
d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy").parse("Tue Aug 25 14:06:30 2015");
```